# Where can I find a list of the HTML 5 validation rules?

Tags: html, validation, w3c-validation

Do services like https://validator.w3.org/ each use their own set of rules or do they draw their rules from a common source (perhaps an IEEE standard)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maintainer of the W3C HTML Checker (validator) here. The checks the HTML Checker does are all based on requirements in particular standards—mainly the [HTML Standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/) but also (for MathML, SVG, and RDFa content in HTML docs), the [MathML spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/MathML3/), the [SVG spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/), and the [RDFa Lite spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/rdfa-lite/).

But there are requirements in the HTML spec that reference other standards, so we also perform checks based on some of those—for example, for the syntax requirements defined in the main [Content Security Policy](https://w3c.github.io/webappsec-csp/) (CSP) spec and in some secondary CSP specs.

Given all that I think it’s important that you see the HTML Checker as more of a checker for helping you catch mistakes you otherwise might have missed, and avoid thinking of it as a “validator”. In that light, it’s not as important whether your documents are officially “valid” or not, and somewhat less important even to know what standards it’s basing its requirements checks on.

In other words, you can just look at it as a [linter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lint_(software))—except that it bases its linting rules on common requirements defined in actual standards (rather than just based on somebody’s arbitrary whims).

By the way, in the interest of making the HTML Checker as useful as possible to authors and developers for catching possible mistakes, I’m regularly adding new checks to it (I only recently added the CSP checks, for example). So if you’re interested in keeping up with its development, you might want to watch the https://github.com/validator/validator repo where the source is hosted.

Also note that when I do add new checks, I nowadays push them out to https://checker.html5.org/ first, then to https://validator.w3.org/nu/ later, and then they eventually get to https://validator.nu/.

Comment: What's the difference between the three locations? Validator.nu calls itself the Living Validator - does that mean it uses WHATWG HTML as a reference vs W3C HTML5 for the others?

Comment: All run the same source from https://github.com/validator/validator but https://checker.html5.org/ has an alternative front-end UI (from the same code base) than https://validator.nu/ & https://html5.validator.nu/ Other that that, those three all return the same results if they’re synced up to the same source revision. But https://validator.nu/ & https://html5.validator.nu/ are maintained by somebody else and get updates slightly less often. I maintain https://checker.html5.org/ directly myself & push changes to it directly (often). So I recommend using https://checker.html5.org/ these days.

Comment: As far as https://validator.w3.org/nu/ I also maintain that directly myself and push to it often. It has the same frontend UI as https://checker.html5.org/ but the results it returns are based on requirements in the W3C forked copy of the HTML spec, which has introduced a handful of differences that are at odds with requirements in the actual upstream HTML Standard at https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/ So again, to make sure you’re checking against the latest upstream (canonical) requirements, I recommend using https://checker.html5.org/